# Symfony 3.4.11 doctrine Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0

Tags: php, symfony, console, doctrine, mapping

I am using Symfony and I upgrade to 3.4.11.

But I have a big problem. When I run the command:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update  --dump-sql
```

in the terminal I have the next error:

```
In ClassMetadataInfo.php line 1400:

  Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0
```

Really, I was search and readed the docs and I can't found the error.

Thanks very much

**UPDATE**

```
$ php bin/console doc:sch:va  -vvv

Mapping
-------


In ClassMetadataInfo.php line 1400:

  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]  
  Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0                     


Exception trace:
 Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo->_validateAndCompleteFieldMapping() at /home/devel/tests4/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php:2355

 Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo->mapField() at /home/devel/tests4/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/AnnotationDriver.php:333

 Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver->loadMetadataForClass() at /home/devel/tests4/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/MappingDriverChain.php:102

 Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\MappingDriverChain->loadMetadataForClass() at /home/devel/tests4/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:151

 Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->doLoadMetadata() at /home/devel/tests4/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:333

 Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata() at /home/devel/tests4/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:78

 Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata() at /home/devel/tests4/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:217

 Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor() at /home/devel/tests4/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:115

 Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getAllMetadata() at /home/devel/tests4/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/SchemaValidator.php:68

 Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaValidator->validateMapping() at /home/devel/tests4/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Console/Command/ValidateSchemaCommand.php:69

 Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\ValidateSchemaCommand->execute() at /home/devel/tests4/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Command/Proxy/ValidateSchemaCommand.php:34

 Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Command\Proxy\ValidateSchemaCommand->execute() at /home/devel/tests4/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:251

 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /home/devel/tests4/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:964

 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /home/devel/tests4/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php:86

 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /home/devel/tests4/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:248

 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /home/devel/tests4/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php:74

 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at /home/devel/tests4/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:148

 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /home/devel/tests4/bin/console:39
```

Comment: I suppose you could try removing the cache directory.  I assume it all worked fine before the update?  You didn't change any of the Doctrine mapping information.

Comment: Nothing, the same mapping.

Comment: You could use **php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate** to check the schema

Comment: As well you can use php bin/console doctrine:schema:update  --dump-sql -vvv to have more debug info and get more information from where its called. Sometimes it give good information where to search for.

Comment: Add the answer in another question because it have more than 2600 chars :)

Comment: Yes, I used **php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate** but I get the same error

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to everyone for try to help me.

I fix my error and I found the correct answer here: https://plus.google.com/+KamilZabdyr/posts/fb5xYGyyyY8

Here the quick fix to a very common error with ORM:

PHP Notice:  Uninitialized string offset: 0 in ?/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php

Usually it's thrown because there is a ORM column name tag empty. So check all your model files for any empty name. E.g:

@ORM\Column(name="", type="string", length=12)

Answer (score 0):

This is the first Google hit for my similar problem:

```
bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff

In MySqlSchemaManager.php line 243:

  Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0
```

When I checked  out the code on other machies it worked but this specific machine got the above failure.
My problem was some interaction with MariaDB.
When I upgraded from:

```
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.34-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

To:

```
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.11-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

The problem went away.

Upgrading to 10.1.38-MariaDB did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the "Uninitialized string offset: 0" with doctrine, from Symfony console.

```
In MySqlSchemaManager.php line 223:
    Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0
```

In my case it was a MariaDB version mismatch between doctrine config and (local) server version. I saw @Samuel Åslund's suggestion to update MariaDB and found that a bit excessive, but it did point me in the direction of a database-version issue.

In **doctrine.yaml** (Symfony 4+)

```
 doctrine:
    dbal:
        server_version: 'mariadb-10.1.36'
```

After installing via symfony-console it was pre-configured with:

```
 doctrine:
    dbal:
        server_version: 'mariadb-10.3.11'
```

Answer (score 0):

For the record I had ~ the same problem while generating the doc with swagger, it was in the annotation of a setter function in an `entity`:

```php
    /**
     * @param Survey[]|[] $surveys
     */
    public function setSurvey(array $surveys = [])
    {
        $this->surveys = $surveys;
    }
```

is wrong when

```php
    /**
     * @param Survey[] $surveys
     */
    public function setSurvey(array $surveys)
    {
        $this->surveys = $surveys;
    }
```

is correct.

The annotation of a potential empty array as argument causes the error (and is also a bad practice I think, a setter function can't have no argument!).